# Add sequence along blocks

Tags: r, sequence

I would like to have a sequence along each `Blocks` as such:

```
Blocks  MySeq     
1      1        
1      2       
2      1        
2      2       
1      1        
1      2        
1      3        
1      4        
3      1        
3      2        
3      3        
4      1
4      2
4      3
4      4
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549792/how-to-add-a-counting-column-based-on-values-in-other-columns-in-r) I have try

```
myDf %>% dplyr::mutate(MySeq= seq(1:length(unique(Blocks)),rle(Blocks)$"lengths")
```

However, the sequence is not resetting with each new block. See below:

```
Blocks  MySeq     
    1      1        
    1      2       
    2      1        
    2      2       
    1      3        
    1      4        
    1      5        
    1      6        
    3      1        
    3      2        
    3      3        
    4      1
    4      2
    4      3
    4      4
```

How can I make a new sequence from each individual `Blocks`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
unlist(sapply(rle(df1$Blocks)$lengths,seq_len))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` by grouping the `rleid` of 'Blocks' and assign (`:=`) 'MySeq' as the sequence of rows.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, MySeq := seq_len(.N) , .(rleid(Blocks))]
df1
#    Blocks MySeq
# 1:      1     1
# 2:      1     2
# 3:      2     1
# 4:      2     2
# 5:      1     1
# 6:      1     2
# 7:      1     3
# 8:      1     4
# 9:      3     1
#10:      3     2
#11:      3     3
#12:      4     1
#13:      4     2
#14:      4     3
#15:      4     4
```

---

Or if we are using `base R`, then `sequence` of `lengths` will get the expected output

```
sequence(rle(df1$Blocks)$lengths)
#[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Blocks = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = "Blocks", row.names = c(NA, 
 -15L), class = "data.frame")
```